# OpenTripPlanner: How to run standalone instance on a port different from default 8080?

Tags: java, server, port, grizzly, opentripplanner

I use this command to get the Grizzly server running:

```
java -Xmx6G -jar otp-0.19.0-shaded.jar --build Data --inMemory
```

and it successfuly runs the Grizzly server on 8080. But because I have want to now use it on a machine that has 8080 occupied I need to run it on e.g. 9090.

when i try:

```
java -Xmx6G -jar otp-0.19.0-shaded.jar -p 9090 --build Data --inMemory
```

Which is suggested in numerous places in the web I will get an error that claims that "-p" is an unsupported command. Any ideas on how I should proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

I use --port to define the http port (and --securePort for the https port).  OTP will open both http and https, so if you want to run multiple instances on a single machine, you have to keep both unique per instance.

This works for me:
java -jar otp*.jar -server --port 55555 --securePort 55556 --router "" --graphs Graph.obj

BTW, the help dialog lists a few other options:
java -jar otp*.jar --help